# How to change local difficulty in all chunks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

On my SMP with a few datapacks when checking the F3 screen the local difficulty is displayed as "??" and the day counter which should be in the same line is straight up missing.

Mobs hurt a lot and often have a lot of armor and enchanted gear so the actual number has to be high.

It's likely due to one of the datapacks I'm using:
Terralith, Incendium, Nullscape
(Only the ones that could affect this)

Can a datapack change local difficulty?
How can I change it in my entire world at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some time but, it appears Aternos servers always have local difficulty in F3 screen as ?? for some reason. By doing some testing with Illusioners (they only give blindness on local difficuly > 2) and changing difficulty it seems to be normal, just hidden.

TL;DR: Nothing to worry about